# Python Pandas Data Frame - Slicing off all but last 30 rows and getting Datetime error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a csv as follows:

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86etF.png)

I then converted it to a data frame:

```
f4 = open('C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\TEST-ASSURANCE FILES\ADBE1.CSV')    
ADBE = pd.read_csv(f4)
```

I want to slice off all but the last 30 rows for the new Data Frame 'ADBE_Last_30_Periods':

```
ADBE_Last_30_Periods = ADBE[-30:]
```

As shown in the CSV file above, the 'Date/Time' Column (column B in the spreadsheet) needs to be converted to a date:

```
ADBE_Last_30_Periods.rename(columns={'Date/Time': 'Date'}, inplace=True)

ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Date'] = ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Date'].reset_index()

ADBE_Last_30_Periods.Date.values.astype('M8[D]')
```

Finally the purpose is to do linear regression on the last 30 periods (which I sliced to separate above):

```
x = ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Date']
y = ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Close']
x = sm.add_constant(x)

ols3 = pd.ols(y = ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Close'], x = ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Date'])
```

I then run the script and get the following error:

```
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime
```

Note that the value error is referring to 'ADBE_Last_30_Periods.Date.values.astype('M8[D]')' shown above.

Please note that when I just run the original file ('ADBE') I don't get this error. The script runs fine and the output looks good. For some reason slicing into only the last 30 periods is causing the Date conversion to screw up. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Use ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ADBE_Last_30_Periods['Date'])

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance. This method seems to create a problem with the regression statements shown in the Original Post. For the line 'x = sm.add_constant(x)' I now get an error saying "TypeError: reduction operation 'var' not allowed for this dtype " So I think this was the issue with the to_datetime method I'd tried using before for this.